# PHP optionally replacing the characters

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace, character, str-replace

I am using PHP to do some sanskrit coding.
I will give example of the rule:
The rule is when $kantha-$talu-$murdha appear in the same sequence, the $talu is duplicated OPTIONALLY.
e.g. aif -> aiif.
The following script gives me the output in case there is only one such occurence.
But the script fails in case where there are more than one such occurences in the string. e.g. $text = "aifkcw"
The following script will give "aiifkccw" only.

Here, because of optionality there are supposed to be four desired outcomes. 
"aifkcw" - without change.
"aiifkcw" - first occurence duplicated, the second left untouched.
"aifkccw" - second occurence duplicated, the first left untouched.
"aiifkccw" - both the occurences duplicated.

I tried some regex also, but without any avail.
any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
$kantha = array("a","A","k","K","g","G","N","h","H");
$talu = array("i","I","c","C","j","J","Y","y","S");
$murdha = array("f","F","w","W","q","Q","R","r","z");
$text = "aifkcw";
echo $text."</br>";
for($i=0;$i<count($kantha);$i++)
{
for($j=0;$j<count($talu);$j++)
{
for($k=0;$k<count($murdha);$k++)
{
$text = str_replace($kantha[$i].$talu[$i].$murdha[$i],$kantha[$i].$talu[$j].$talu[$j].$murdha[$k],$text);
}
}
}
echo $text."</br>";
?>
```

Comment: do `$kantha-$talu-$murdha` have to be in that order and sequential?  are fai, iaf, fia, akif valid?

Comment: also - can you post some test values?  more than just `aifkcw`?  what it more than one thing matches?  what if it's `aifcwsy`?  (i'm sure that's not a word but it's only an example)

Comment: Yes. $kantha-$talu-$murdha have to be in the same order.

Comment: @gloomy.penguin -> The Idea is that whenever this combination of three letters appear, there will be duplication of the middle letter optionally. e.g. "dhavaiftbgcw" has two matches. One is "aif" and the other is "gcw". So in this case both the duplications are optional. The without duplication: "dhavaiftbgcw" . Only first duplicated : "dhavaiiftbgcw". Only the second duplicated : "dhavaiftbgccw". Both duplicated : ""dhavaiiftbgccw".

Comment: What if it's aifcwsy ? -> The length before and after doesn't matter. In that case it would be still aifcwsy / aiifcwsy - because of optionality.

Comment: and if there's three occurrences? you need all combinations of normal and double for each thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... I took out the case sensitive part then I realized that might be part of your rules so you might need to add that back in.  I need to go to work so I don't have time to explain all of this.  I needed to use array pointers so you might want to read up on [next()](https://www.php.net/next) and [current()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php).

**edit**:  i added a lot of comments to try and help you understand what is happening here.

```
<?php
  
 
// this is an array of the input values to use below 
$strings_to_test = array('aifkcwh', 'aifkcwhsz', 'kim', 'aif');  
 

 // get all possible combianations of $kantha+$talu+$murdha
$combinations = get_string_combinations(); 
display($combinations,'$combinations'); 

foreach ($strings_to_test as $stti => $string)  // 'aifkcwh', 'aifkcwhsz', 'kim', 'aif'
{
    
    $values = array($string);  
    reset($values); 

    display("<br/>-----------------------------------------"); 
    display("value: $string");  // first iteration "aifkcwh"

    // loop through $values using an array pointer 
    // while the current array pointer position is not null/false
    while(current($values)!==false)
    {
        // on the first iteration, $values will be the inputted string 
        // from $strings_to_test... our example is "aifkcwh"
        $value = current($values); 
        
       display("current value: $string"); 
        
        // for each possible combination of $kantha.$talu.$murdha
        // let's say our first combination is "aif"
        foreach($combinations as $ci => $combination)
        {  
            // look and see if the current value we are looking
            // at ("aifkcwh") contains this combination string  
            if (stripos($value,$combination)!==false)
            {
                // if it does... we perform the string mutation
                // "aif" does exist in the string "aifkcwh"
                
                // get the second letter in the combination string
                $single = $combination[1];   // i 
                
                // double that second letter
                $double = str_repeat($single, 2); // ii 
                
                // create a new string that is the combination with the 
                // second letter doubled... 
                $newcom = str_ireplace($single, $double, $combination); // aiif 
                
                // replace that string in $values so that
                // aifkcwh becomes aiifkcwh
                $newval = str_ireplace($combination, $newcom, $value); // aiifkcwh
                
                // does the new value ("aiifkcwh") exist in $values?  
                // have we already recorded this mutation?  
                if (!in_array($newval,$values)) 
                { 
                    // if not... append it to the array $values
                    $values[] = $newval; 
                    display("added to array for $value: $newval");

                    // now, values would go from being = array([0]=>'aifkcwh'); 
                    // to array ([ 0] => 'aifkcwh', [1] => 'aiifkcwh' ); 
                }
                else 
                {
                    display("not added because it already exists: $newval");
                }
            } 
        } // <-- end of the foreach statement, this will go through all combinations 
          //     in our combinations array for this particular value which is currently aifkcwh


        // next($values) increments the array pointer so that we move to the next
        // value in the $values array.  since we just added a value, 
        // $values now contains array ([ 0] => 'aifkcwh', [1] => 'aiifkcwh' ); 
        
        // before this statement index 0, current($values) == 'aifkcwh'
        next($values);  
        // after this statement index 1, current($values) == 'aiifkcwh'
        // for the next loop, we will test this string for all the combinations
        // if there is no next value, the `while` loop will end 
    }  
    
    // after we have gone through every possible combination for "aifkcwh",
    // we will have something like this: 
    /*
        Array
          (
                [0] => aifkcwh
                [1] => aiifkcwh
                [2] => aifkccwh
                [3] => aiifkccwh
          )
    */
    // and we add that to the $output array that contains an index for 
    // each input string, which contains all possible mutations of that string 
    $output[$string] = $values; 
}

 // display the results.  
display($output,'$output');  
 
 
 // ================================================================
 // functions 
 // ================================================================
 
 
 // get all possible combinations of $kantha.$talu.$murdha
 function get_string_combinations()
 {
     $kantha = array("a","k","g","n","h");
     $talu   = array("i","c","j","y","s");
     $murdha = array("f","w","q","r","z");
     
     $combinations = array(); 
      
     foreach($kantha as $k) // "a","k","g","n","h"
     { 
        foreach($talu as $t) // "i","c","j","y","s"
        { 
            foreach($murdha as $m) // "f","w","q","r","z"
            {
                $combinations[] = $k.$t.$m; 
            } 
        } 
     } 
     // this gives us an array if 125 items 
     /*
     $combinations = 
        Array
        (
             [0] => aif
             [1] => aiw
             [2] => aiq
             [3] => air
             [4] => aiz
             .... 
             [121] => hsw
             [122] => hsq
             [123] => hsr
             [124] => hsz
        ) 
     */
     return $combinations;
 }
 
 
 // display variables to see what the code is doing 
 function display($var,$label=null)
 {
     if (is_array($var))
     { 
        print "<pre>$label = \n".print_r($var,true)."</pre>"; 
     }
     else print "$var <br/>"; 
 }
?>
```

complete output from the program besides `$combinations` because it is rather long...

```
----------------------------------------- 
value: aifkcwh 
current value: aifkcwh 
added to array for aifkcwh: aiifkcwh 
added to array for aifkcwh: aifkccwh 
current value: aifkcwh 
added to array for aiifkcwh: aiifkccwh 
current value: aifkcwh 
not added because it already exists: aiifkccwh 
current value: aifkcwh 

----------------------------------------- 
value: aifkcwhsz 
current value: aifkcwhsz 
added to array for aifkcwhsz: aiifkcwhsz 
added to array for aifkcwhsz: aifkccwhsz 
added to array for aifkcwhsz: aifkcwhssz 
current value: aifkcwhsz 
added to array for aiifkcwhsz: aiifkccwhsz 
added to array for aiifkcwhsz: aiifkcwhssz 
current value: aifkcwhsz 
not added because it already exists: aiifkccwhsz 
added to array for aifkccwhsz: aifkccwhssz 
current value: aifkcwhsz 
not added because it already exists: aiifkcwhssz 
not added because it already exists: aifkccwhssz 
current value: aifkcwhsz 
added to array for aiifkccwhsz: aiifkccwhssz 
current value: aifkcwhsz 
not added because it already exists: aiifkccwhssz 
current value: aifkcwhsz 
not added because it already exists: aiifkccwhssz 
current value: aifkcwhsz 

----------------------------------------- 
value: kim 
current value: kim 

----------------------------------------- 
value: aif 
current value: aif 
added to array for aif: aiif 
current value: aif 
$output = 
Array
(
    [aifkcwh] => Array
        (
            [0] => aifkcwh
            [1] => aiifkcwh
            [2] => aifkccwh
            [3] => aiifkccwh
        )

    [aifkcwhsz] => Array
        (
            [0] => aifkcwhsz
            [1] => aiifkcwhsz
            [2] => aifkccwhsz
            [3] => aifkcwhssz
            [4] => aiifkccwhsz
            [5] => aiifkcwhssz
            [6] => aifkccwhssz
            [7] => aiifkccwhssz
        )

    [kim] => Array
        (
            [0] => kim
        )

    [aif] => Array
        (
            [0] => aif
            [1] => aiif
        )

)
```

Comment: One more question. I converted this script to a function and want to pass one array as argument and get the output to an array. The name of the array in my script is $text. I tried doing $values = $text; instead of $values = array('aifkcw');. This didn't work though. The script hanged for quite long time. Any Idea why this may have happened.

Comment: oh... yeah... i thought you meant something else so i updated the code to take in multiple strings to test.  `$values` has to be an array so you can add items to it.  if you just do `$values = $text;` then `$values` is just a string, not an array... you need to do `$values = array($text);` and then it will work.

Comment: The output as an individual script is fine.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to have a look at this page and offer your remarks ? https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ekcbW9ivF7muz-t-8sZJ4_XOOo78edKvs_0YO7tVNp0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm not trying to be mean... but if the output is what you want and the code should be very easy to modify to your own needs.  I don't want to just give you a big chunk of code and have you use it but also have no clue how it works to the point you can't even read it to figure out how to provide the input in a correct format.  I think it's a failing on my part.  Tell me if you need me to explain more.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying the code. I could make out the issue with integrating the code with my script. This code worked well when the output didn't fall within this $kantha-$talu-$murdha kind. When the output also satisfies similar situation - it would continue infinitely. So my script hanged. But this is the best solution found. Thanks for painstakingly clarifying the code. With regards.